# How to invert background color based on the light/dark theme in Bootstrap 5.3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

In Bootstrap 5.3, we are able to specify a theme to use for the site. Out of the box there are two supported theme **Dark** and **Light**.

If I set my `<html data-bs-theme="dark">`, I want to set the site navbar to a light color. At the same time, when setting `<html data-bs-theme="light">` I want the navbar to have dark background colors.

If there a specific class in Bootstrap that can be used to invert the colors based on the current theme?

I tried using the `body-*` classes to accomplish, but that does not do what I want. I want to select the opposite of the current `text-body` or `bg-body`.

```
<nav class="navbar text-body bg-body">
       
</nav>
```

How to invert background color based on the light/dark theme in Bootstrap 5.3?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow, but can't you just add `data-bs-theme="dark"` to your `nav` element?

Comment: @sallf that would make my navbar always dark even if the `data-bs-theme="light"` is set on the `<html>` tag.

Comment: @Jay I guess you're using a JS theme toggler, and you want the nav to always be inverted? In that case I would still use salif's suggestion and then modify your JS toggler to flip both `data-bs-theme` attributes.

Comment: Otherwise you can define `.bg-body-inverted` and `.text-body-inverted` classes as swapped versions of the theme bg/fg. There's no built-in class for this.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with IFRAMEs in 5.3.  Even though it's set to dark its setting the backgrounds to white somehow.  If I flip it back to light it goes with the default transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mr. J's approach will invert `.bg-body` and `.text-body` globally. I'm not sure how useful that is because you could (should) just use the opposite theme in that case.

---

#### Nested color modes (JS)

I would use salif's suggestion, which Bootstrap calls [nested color modes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color-modes/#nesting-color-modes):

```
<body data-bs-theme="dark">
  <nav id="nav" data-bs-theme="light" class="navbar text-body bg-body">
```

Then in your JS color mode toggler, flip both `data-bs-theme` attributes:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('themer').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const current = document.documentElement.getAttribute('data-bs-theme')
    const inverted = current == 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark'
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-bs-theme', inverted)
    document.getElementById('nav').setAttribute('data-bs-theme', current)
  })
}
```

```html
<html data-bs-theme="dark">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <nav data-bs-theme="light" id="nav" class="navbar text-body bg-body">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Inverted navbar</span>
      <a id="themer" href="#" class="btn btn-primary m-3" role="button" data-bs-toggle="button">Toggle theme</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

---

#### Inverted classes (CSS only)

If you want to do it with just CSS, define `-inverted` classes to swap foreground and background:

- `.bg-body-inverted` (inverted theme background) gets mapped to `--bs-body-color` (theme foreground)
- `.text-body-inverted` (inverted theme foreground) gets mapped to `--bs-body-bg` (theme background)

These `-inverted` versions will invert fg/bg regardless of color mode:

```css
.bg-body-inverted {
  background-color: var(--bs-body-color) !important;
}

.text-body-inverted {
  color: var(--bs-body-bg) !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body data-bs-theme="dark">
  <nav class="navbar text-body-inverted bg-body-inverted">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <span class="navbar-brand text-body-inverted mb-0 h1">Inverted navbar</span>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Isn't there a built in approach for this? BS 5.3 seems to support dark and light mode. I assumed that there is an easy way to convert between the two without to specifically assign a color to each component.

Comment: [Nesting color modes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color-modes/#nesting-color-modes) is the built-in approach. It's more robust because `data-bs-theme` automatically toggles the theming throughout all children.

Comment: For example take `.navbar-brand`. Using nested theme, the brand's color gets toggled automatically via `data-bs-theme`. Using CSS, the text color has to be inverted explicitly (in addition to the parent nav): `class="navbar-brand text-body-inverted"`

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand what you mean by "convert between the two without specifically assigning a color to each component." If you want a particular component to diverge from the selected theme, what other option would there be?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using css variables.

First you define your main theme colours in :root

```
:root {
  --bg-body-dark: #202124;
  --bg-body-light: #fff;
  --text-body-light: #191919;
  --text-body-dark: #f8f9fa;
}
```

Then you assign a colour to use for the `.bg-body` class with the "light" theme:

```
[data-bs-theme=light] {
  --bg-body: --bg-body-light;
  --text-body: --text-body-light;
}
```

And which colour to use for `.bg-body` with the "dark" theme:

```
[data-bs-theme=dark] {
  --bg-body: --bg-body-dark;
  --text-body: --text-body-dark;
}
```

Now when you toggle between themes, the `nav` background and text colour should update accordingly.

Bootstrap 5.3 defines it's own theme colour variables:

[image: bootstrap 5.3 theme variables]

Feel free to use these instead of the ones I declared above.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't understand how bootstrap supplies all these variables, but doesn't give us something like `--bs-theme` that derives meaning from the current theme - text would be light when the background is dark and vise versa. I mean essentially they're saying if you want to use dark or light, you have to do some very heavy lifting, which seems to be the opposite of everything else in bootstrap...